# OTP encryption with ceasar encryption

Tags: encryption

Why not to use OTP to encrypt more than one message but every encryption after the XOR do something like subtitution/ceasar cipher on the CT?

Answer (score 0):

Reusing a one-time-pad is bad because it gives you information about  the key.

```
p: a plaintext message to be encrypted: p_1 p_2 ... p_n
e_i: encryption of p_i with key k_i
otp: e_i = p_i^k_i for ii in 1..n
```

If you encrypt multiple messages and you xor them together you get   something like

```
e1_1^e2_1 = p1_1^k_1^k_1^p2_1
```

and since `k_1^k_1` cancels that becomes

```
e1_1^e2_1 = p1_1^p2_1
```

So you instantly learn information about the messages, but if you happened to know something about the input, you also learn something about the key.

By something like Caesar cipher you might mean

```
e2_1 = p2_1^(k_1+13)
```

That's assuming a 26-letter alphabet for your key and message space.
Unfortunately after 2 messages, your key wraps again, and you're back to the same problem you had before.
(there are other big problems too)

more generally, whatever simple thing you do , you give away information about the messages and typically key.  The attacker can typically set up a big matrix of equations and use linear algebra to solve for the key once you give them enough information.

However if you take the simple thing you're doing and make it more and more complex and eventually get to a point where

```
kn: the key for the nth message
kn = f(k,n) for some function k
```

such that an attacker cannot learn significant information about `f(k,n) given`f(k,m)`for`n != m`, you've invented a stream cipher.
People do use stream ciphers all the time; they are not as secure as OTP, but they are a core of internet security.
The trick of course is figuring out a good function`f`; describing how to do that is beyond the margin of this question.  (And besides I don't actually have that skill).

Comment: And something like this: cipher=m^key and then shuffle the characters? The attacker won't get any information about our key or our plain text if he won't know our shuffling function

Comment: If it's actually true that the attacker won't get any information then sure.  It won't be though Also, note that the shuffling function cannot be the same more than once.  It's also generally assumed the attacker knows all your functions, just doesn't know their keys.